# How to add multiple users email id to share file from a google drive api using node js

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

When I run this code , an error came ==>

> The permission type field is required.

> How can i use multiple Email addressess to share the file of google drive in node js

```
async function updateFilePermissions(){
    try{
        const fileId = fileId;
let resourceContents = [{
    role: 'writer',
    type: 'user',
    emailAddress: 'SomeEmail@gmail.com',
  },{
    role: 'writer',
    type: 'user',
    emailAddress: 'someEmail@gmail.com'
  }];

  await drive.permissions.create({

    resource: resourceContents,
    fileId: fileId,
    sendNotificationEmail: true,
    fields: '*'

  });
 /* 
    webViewLink: View the file in browser
    webContentLink: Direct download link 
    */
    const result = await drive.files.get({
      fileId: fileId,
      fields: 'webViewLink, webContentLink',
    });
    console.log(result.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: fileId is the id of the file you want to add permissions to.

Comment: Okay Thanks  , Can you also tell me how can i use multiple email addresses to share a file of drive.

Comment: In your script, `role: 'Owner',` is used. Do you want to transfer the ownership of the file? If my understanding is correct, how are you retrieving your access token? It's OAuth2 or a service account? And, can you provide the mimeType of the file of `fileId`?

Comment: >No i dont want to transfer the ownership , i just wrote that by mistake and I am retrieving my access token with OAuth2 , mime type of file => 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create the permissions to 2 email addresses as `role: 'writer'` and `type: 'user'`.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for Node.js.
- You have permission for creating the permissions to the file. And also, your access token can be used for creating the permissions to the file.

Unfortunately, in the current stage, an array cannot be used for `resource` of `drive.permissions.create` of googleapis for Node.js. In this case, please use it in a loop. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```js
let resourceContents = [{
    role: 'writer',
    type: 'user',
    emailAddress: 'SomeEmail@gmail.com',
  },{
    role: 'writer',
    type: 'user',
    emailAddress: 'someEmail@gmail.com'
  }];

  await drive.permissions.create({

    resource: resourceContents,
    fileId: fileId,
    sendNotificationEmail: true,
    fields: '*'

  });
```

#### To:

```js
const emails = ['SomeEmail@gmail.com', 'someEmail@gmail.com'];
for (let i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
  const res = await drive.permissions
    .create({
      resource: {
        role: "writer",
        type: "user",
        emailAddress: emails[i],
      },
      fileId: fileId,
      sendNotificationEmail: true,
      fields: "*",
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.errors));
  if (res) console.log(res.data);
}
```

- When this script is run, the permission of `role: "writer", type: "user"` for the file of `fileId` is given to the emails of `emails`.

#### References:

- [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)
- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)